# SilverLight, WCf service, Datetime.Today

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, datetime, timezone

I have SilverLight App and wcf service.
I have model

```
public class MyModel
{
        public DateTime MyDate {get;set;} 
        ...
}
```

On server side i did:

```
MyModel.MyDate = DateTime.ToDay
```

and return model to client

On Client

```
var taskGet = await _context.Load(_context.GetMyModelQuery()).AsTask();
MyModel= taskGet .Entities.FirstOrDefault();
```

Server and client are in different time zones
Server has +8h to UTC
Client has +3H(my browser) UTC

On server DateTime.ToDay return 20/03/2015

But on client i had 19/03/2015

Why is this happening?

Comment: Well you've explained it yourself - they're in two different time zones, so they can easily be observing two different days...

Comment: Isn't that normal? Since `Today` returns `DateTime` as `Local`, your dates _can_ be different as well.

Comment: It is not normal. Data is on server 20/03/2015 5:24 pm now. Data on my computer is 20 / 03 /2015 12:24 pm and my browser shows  -1 day (19/03/2015)

Comment: Well your question doesn't mention anything about the time of day at which you observed this. That's pretty crucial information. You also haven't shown anything in terms of what you're doing on the client side, which makes it hard to help you...

Comment: this answer was to deleted

Comment: If i use DateTime.Now, all work well. I think that problem in time

Comment: DateTime.Today return 20/03/ 12 00 00 AM - it is Midnight
The client makes an implicit conversion, taking into account the time zone when receiving data. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

On client side,

```
<sdk:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding MyDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />

MyDate = MyModel.Mydate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found temp solution.

```
var myDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```